# pdf2svg leads to blurry images

Tags: pdf, svg, inkscape, image-conversion

I'm trying to convert a pdf figure to svg so I can edit some details with Inkscape. The problem I have is that the import changes slightly through some sort of smoothing.

In particular, this is the original figure:

[image]

And this is the figure after converting to SVG

[image]

This is the output of pdf2svg, which is exactly the same I get if I use Inkscape directly.

I attach a link where you can get both files.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/domxcc8pncyouy6/images.tar.gz?dl=0

Do you know a workaround to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the SVG it is hard to tell for sure.  However it looks like the "heat map" portion of your PDF/SVG may be a low resolution bitmap that is being enlarged in the page.

By default, SVG renderers will use interpolation when enlarging an image.  This gives the image a smoothed/blurry look at large scales.

You could try locating the `<image>` element in your SVG and adding the attribute `image-rendering="pixelated"` to the `<image>` tag.  Some browsers support that option and will scale the image using the nearest-neighbour scaling method.

Otherwise you may need to extract the image from the PDF or SVG; resample it at a higher (eg. 4x or 8x) resolution; then reinsert it back into the file.

1. Find the image in the SVG file (`<image id="image5" .../>`
2. Extract the Base64 encoded image from the DataURI. And decode it using a Base64 decoder.
3. Multiply the image resolution using an editor, cusch as Photoshop or Gimp.
4. Encode the file back to Base64
5. Update that `<image>` element with the new Base64.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have attached a link where you can get the files if you feel like having a look. I tried editing the SVG but it doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: Yes. As I suspected it is a low-resolution (65x43) bitmap. If you add the `image-rendering` attribute it works in Chrome, but not FF (see https://jsfiddle.net/oowz03vy/). If you need it to work everywhere then AFAIK there is no other way to get the pixellated look other than increasing its resolution as I suggested.